# how to check whether button exist or not in actionscript

Tags: flash, button, actionscript

Im new to actionscript .How to check whether button exist or not in actionscript.I guess using removechildname function, tried it with no succcess.Please help me out.

Comment: Can you give more information? Do you know the button id and it's parent? What do you want to achieve because this seems a weird problem you should have ? You can use a try-catch for the parent.button and see if it works

Comment: What do mean 'exist'? Is this a button that you have put into the Display List? Did you create this button programmatically (using AS3) or manually inside the Flash program? Have you tried: if(buttonName.stage){trace("I exist!")}else{trace("I DON'T exist!")}

Comment: The button is dynamically created with dynamic name attribute.My problem is i have a video playing when the cue point is reached im generating few buttons over the video and im also storing those dynamic name values in an array and on video progress when the specified time is reached lets say 10sec after the cue point has occurred using the values in array i need to remove the generated button.Now

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this will help you out:

```
// Since you have a array with names, i think you can do this:

// Get the length
var lengthOfButtonsNamesArray:int = buttonsNamesArray.length;
// looop through your array of names
for(var index:int = 0; index < lengthOfButtonsNamesArray; ++index){
    // getting the button inside your buttons container using the array of names and getChildByName Method
    var button:DisplayObject = buttonsContainer.getChildByName(buttonsNamesArray[index]) as DisplayObject;
    // if the button was found
    if(button != null){
        // remove it
        buttonsContainer.removeChild(button);
    }
}

///////////////////////
// OR
//////////////////////

// If you are sure that there are only buttons inside your buttons container and you want to remove all of them 

// Check the amount of children inside your buttons container
// while its greater then zero, remove the child at index of zero
while(buttonsContainer.numChildren > 0){
    buttonsContainer.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

I didn't test it but I'm pretty sure that this works, anyway let me know how you're doing there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [contains()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#contains%28%29):

```
if (this.contains(myButton))
{
    // then we know myButton exists inside of this class
    this.removeChild(myButton); // removeElement(), in some situations
}

if (myDisplayContainer.contains(myButton))
{
    // then we know myButton exists inside of myDisplayContainer
    myDisplayContainer.removeChild(myButton); // removeElement(), in some
                                              // situations
}
```